# Display Client Errors and then Server Errors on Angular's Reactive Form after submission

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular2-forms

Using Angular 12 I have a simple example form with Client and Server Validation.

1. I want to show Client Validation errors only after first Form submission;
2. I will show Server Validation errors after Client Validation is succeeded.

   Server Validation errors are added as 'incorrect' field in Form Field errors.
3. I am using Reactive Forms.

The form is working as expected but I'm not sure if my implementation is the best option.

**Component's HTML**

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <label for="email">Email</label>
  <input id="email" type="text" formControlName="email">
  
  <span class="error" *ngIf="form.get('email')?.invalid && form.get('email')?.touched">
    {{form.get('email')?.errors?.incorrect}}
    <ng-container *ngIf="form.get('email')?.errors?.required">Email required</ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngIf="form.get('email')?.errors?.email">Invalid email</ng-container>
  </span>

  <button type="submit" (click)="send()" [disabled]="submitted">Send</button>
</form>
```

**Component's Typescript**

```
export class Component implements OnInit {

  form: FormGroup;
  submitted: boolean;

  constructor(private service: Service) { 

    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({ 
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
    });

    this.submitted = false;

  }

  send() {

    this.submitted = true;
    this.form.markAllAsTouched();

    if (this.form.valid) {

      this.service.send({email: this.form.value.email}).subscribe(
        
        (next: Payload<Response>) => { 
          console.log("SUCCESS");
        },

        (error) => {
          if (error.status === 400)
            new FormGroupErrorBuilder(this.form).setErrors(error.errors);
          this.submitted = false;
        }

      );

    } else {
      this.submitted = false;
    }

  }    

}
```

**FormGroupErrorBuilder**

```
This is how I am adding server errors to Angular's FormGroup:

export class FormGroupErrorBuilder {

  formGroup: FormGroup;

  constructor(formGroup: FormGroup) {
    this.formGroup = formGroup;
  }

  setErrors(errors: Error[]) {

    for (let error of errors) {

      var control = this.formGroup.get(error.name);

      if (control)
        control.setErrors({ incorrect: error.message });
        
    }

  } 

}
```

**Questions**

1. Is it acceptable to use `this.form.markAllAsTouched();` to fire validation for all form fields on first submit?
2. Using the condition `*ngIf="form.get('email')?.invalid && form.get('email')?.touched"` a good option to show the form field errors?

Any suggestion to improve the code is welcome ...

**Note:**

I am using `submitted` variable to control if the submit button is disabled or not and to change its CSS styles.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to Async custom validators [in the docs](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#creating-asynchronous-validators):

If you create your formGroup with the option {updateOption:'submit'} I think you can achieve in other way

some like: e.g. (I put the validator in the FormGroup, you can put it in the own control Email) -then you should change the "validateEmail" function.

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({ 
  email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
},{updateOption:'submit',asyncValidator:this.validateEmail()});


  validateEmail(): AsyncValidatorFn {
    return (group: FormGroup): Promise<ValidationErrors | null> | Observable<ValidationErrors | null> => {
      return 
         this.service.send({email:group.value.email}).map(res=>{
            if (res.success)
                return null
            return { repeat: "name yet register" }
         })
      )))

    };
  }
```

NOTE: I don't see clear in your code, when you subscribe to the service. You "catch" the error, Generally an API return some like `{success:true}` or `{error:'the email is yet!'}`, but don't return a status 400 if ther'e not an error in the call -your API can response some like above but you received the response in success, not in error.

Comment: I was checking some API and some of them return a 400 error when the request is malformed. For example, when the data is incorrect. Others seem to return an HTTP 422 error instead of 400 when validation fails. Others do as you said and return and HTTP success code but with errors in the response. I am not sure which one is better.

Comment: @MiguelMoura, you can use `pipe(catchError(err=>{success:false})` if you want to get all the response in the subscribe(next)