# Reactive Forms and Custom errors on formControl

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I've been puzzled by the following issue;

I created a reactive form group with some props. Once these are filled out, I want to give the option for the API/backend to set an error message on one of the form controls, which all seems fine and works (see StackBlitz).
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ycvbgq?file=src/app/app.component.ts

HTML

```html
    <form [formGroup]="form">
     <div class="col-md-6 mb-3 input-gap" *ngIf="editMode | async">
      <input formControlName="userName" placeholder="first name" />
      <input formControlName="userLastName" placeholder="last name" />
     </div>
    <button class="btn btn-info mr-1" (click)="addError()">Error</button>
    </form>
```

TS

```js
    addError() {
      this.form.controls['userName'].setErrors({
        backend: { message: 'My best wishes' },
      });
      this.form.updateValueAndValidity();
    }
```

So let's set the names to "Luke" and "Skywalker" and update the form to simulate the call. We get our errors object with whatever the backend wishes to say.

Now try toggling the editing button ("Stop Editing" and then "Edit Content"). As you can see, once you stop editing and then try to edit the content again, the "Errors" disappear. I thought the errors would need to be manually cleared?

So my question is how can I keep the Errors messages around or would I be forced to use AsyncValidators in this case?

Comment: I've answered your question but please add all relevant code into the question instead of just an external link. External links can break making this question useless to future readers.

Comment: Just add in both cases:`<div *ngIf="this.form.controls['userName'].errors">{{this.form.controls['userName'].errors.backend.message}}</div>` remember that a FormControl exist if is declared in the .ts (It's not neccesary exist a input in .html). BTW I feel it's better you use an async validator like it's showed in [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68579412/display-client-errors-and-then-server-errors-on-angulars-reactive-form-after-su/68581466#68581466)

Comment: Thanks @ChrisHamilton, I've added the most basic of the code which should get the message across.

Answer (score 2):

Destroying the input element then recreating it resets the form control. You can set them to `display: none` instead.

```html
<div class="col-md-6 mb-3 input-gap" [style.display]="(editMode | async) ? '' : 'none'">
      <input formControlName="userName" placeholder="first name" />
      <input formControlName="userLastName" placeholder="last name" />
</div>
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-te4wb1?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: I was hoping that would not be the answer as this example is just a tiny extraction of our full app, and I'm trying very hard to keep the DOM nodes in check as we depend on external libraries which use a lot of additional nodes. I'll read up some more on how to do this with AsyncValidators or add on return a Custom Validator to the form. the way my boss wants to implement is that the frontend doesn't know what is right or wrong... that's why I wanted to avoid the Validators

Comment: @RobertLeeuwerink makes more sense to me to validate before attempting a request. Happens in realtime instead of waiting for a response. ie. you can show an error while the user is typing. Also less useless traffic on your server. Validation at all layers never hurts either.

Comment: You are right on that, which has been built in just not the example as that's a simplification. what the frontend cannot do is access all the information the backend has available. which in turn makes it hard to write the Validator for this

Comment: Makes sense, looks like you found a good solution.

Answer (score 2):

To persist an error message like this you would be better off by passing the message into a CustomValidator, which would maintain the error message until a user approves the Validation or removes the validator. Also to remove the delay of displaying the error I'm setting the error object at the same time, just like I'm removing it too.

Solution 2, would be to do the same however then with an AsyncCustomValidator and a Service that holds all the messages with an id once the message with that id gets removed the Validator should return null and therefore pass and clear the error.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-arbklk?file=src/app/app.component.ts

TS

```js
    addError() {
     const msg = 'My best wishes';
     this.form.controls['userName'].setErrors({ backend: msg });
     this.form.controls['userName'].addValidators(apiMsgValidator(msg));
     this.form.updateValueAndValidity();
    }
```

Custom Validator

```js
    export function apiMsgValidator(msg: string): ValidatorFn {
      return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
        const bakendMsg = true;
        return bakendMsg ? { backend: msg } : null;
      };
     }
```

By going about it this way the error doesn't clear away by any interaction until you remove the Validator. If the FormGroup were in a Service the user can also change routes while maintaining the error.

The main disadvantage with display:none would be that the errors will get cleared after touching any one of the controls or changing routes.

The new problem is how do you clear this specific error. As said above we give the user a control button. A reference to the Validator is going to be needed too for us to be able to remove the Custom Validator.

HTML

```html
     <button
      *ngIf="form.controls.userName.errors?.backend?.id"
      class="btn btn-dark"
      (click)="removeValidator(form.controls.userName.errors?.backend?.id)"
    >
      {{ 'I have read and understood the error, clear error.' }}
    </button>
```

TS

```js
      validations = {};

      addError() {
        const id = '17';
        const message = 'My best wishes';
        this.validations = {
          ...this.validations,
          [id]: apiMsgValidator(message, id),
        };
        this.form.controls['userName'].setErrors({ backend: { id, message } });
        this.form.controls['userName'].addValidators(this.validations[id]);
        this.form.updateValueAndValidity();
      }

      removeValidator(id: string) {
       this.form.controls['userName'].removeValidators(this.validations[id]);
       this.form.controls['userName'].setErrors({ backend: null });
       this.form.updateValueAndValidity();
      }
```